# How to read all files from the resource folder of a SpringBoot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot v2.1.2.RELEASE application. 
I have this folder ../src/main/resources/icons/svg/white/

I am trying to list all the files of the folder But It seems that the folder does not exist

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SvgManagerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SvgManagerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {      
        try {
            File folder = new File("icons/svg/white/");
            listFilesForFolder(folder);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the  [`ResourceUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html)

```
File folder= ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:icons/svg/white/");
```

Comment: This threw "class path resource [<my path>] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system" when I ran from the JAR.